# mysql select from 3 tables not working

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables on my database with the following data:

tb_collection: id_collection, name

tb_collection_product: id, id_collection, id_product

tb_product: id_product, photo

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Select the last 2 products of each collection...I've tried group by with no luck.

Comment: @user1541940: Code with the table definitions plz

Comment: Hey Chris, I'm just a mysql beginner trying to learn, I tried using a select, then a while, then a select, then a while, etc...Now I'm searching over the internet for a better and right solution. :)

Comment: `tb_collection_product` is redundant, just add a column `category_id` to `tb_product`

Comment: its not redundant since the products table has a category column and some products can be related to a collection or not.

Comment: one thing that you need to understand do not write same colon name in different tables,Because same colon name will not be joined

Comment: change your colon name and use the below query using new names

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT   tb_collection.id_collection,tb_collection.name , 
         tb_collection_product.id , tb_collection_product.id_collection, 
         tb_collection_product.id_product, tb_product.id_product, 
         tb_product.photo 
FROM     tb_collection 
             INNER JOIN tb_collection_product 
                    ON tb_collection.id_collection=tb_collection_product.id_collection 
             INNER JOIN tb_product 
                    ON tb_collection_product.id = tb_product.id_product 
ORDER BY tb_collection.id_collection DESC limit 2
```

Comment: I just got a mysql syntax error near .id_product ORDER BY tb_collection.id_collection DESC limit 2

Comment: after i formatted your code, please fix this line `LEFT JOIN tb_collection_product. id=tb_product.id_product`. the reason why the user got syntax error.

Comment: You are missing the table name and the `ON` clause on the left join are you not?

Answer (score 0):

Just got it working doing the following:

Added a new column called "show" as a tinyint field with default 0 and 1 for selected.
Then, the following mysql:

SELECT tb_product.photo, tb_collection_product.* FROM tb_product,tb_collection_product WHERE tb_collection_product.show=1 AND tb_collection_product.id_product = tb_product.id_product